# What is the difference between Hadd and Qisas?

Tags: sharia, fiqh, punishment

Both of them are physical punishments that are related to the human body. What makes these two punishment different?

Answer (score 2):

*In the name of Allah the merciful the compassionate*

---

That's right, they are both include physical punishments based on the Islamic rules. But there is a difference between them. The difference will be explained briefly.

### Qisas (law of retaliation)

Is punishment which is ordered by God to do when someone is damaged by another person, for example a man is killed by another person, and in this case the guilty person should be killed (retaliated)�. law of retaliation is set by God.

> ...Should anyone aggress against you, assail him in the manner he
> assailed you.[2:194]
>
> O' you who have Faith! Retaliation (Qisas) if prescribed for you in
> the matter of the (unlawfully) murdered: the freeman for the freeman,
> the slave for the slave, the female for the female. But for him who if
> forgiven somewhat by his (aggrieved religious) brother, then
> prosecution (for blood-wit) should be made according to a fair manner
> (ma'ruf) and let the payment be made to him with kindliness. This is
> an alleviation from your Lord, and a mercy; so whoever transgresses
> the limits after this, he shall have a painful punishment.[1:178]

### Hadd

But hadd is a punishment set for the cases, Muslims disrespect some Islamic rules such as drinking, eating in public in the Ramadan.
For example, pre-marital sex is a sin punishable by the Islamic court. If an unmarried man and an unmarried woman are found guilty of fornication in an Islamic court, their punishment will be as the following:

> The woman and the man who fornicate scourge each of them a hundred
> whips; and in the matter of God s religion, let no tenderness for them
> seize you if you believe in God and the Last Day; and let a party of
> the believers witness their punishment. (24:2)

---

**For more information you can visit:**

- [www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/)