# What are the conditions to harm someone if the person did something terrible to you or your family in the following scenarios? (no killing)

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, punishment

I pondered a while ago when it is allowed to harm someone for the damage the person has afflicted upon yourself or a family member and till what extent?

Let's say someone has stolen something from you, would you then be allowed to go to the house from that person and beat that person unconscious? 
And what should you do when someone harms a family member of yours?

Comment: Read the answer here : https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10402/what-is-the-difference-between-hadd-and-qisas/11836#11836

Comment: I don't find the reference link of much use since the only thing I can conclude out of it is that the one whom damage is afflicted to has the right to use violence equivalently. Or you go to an islamic judge which is not here in my country.

Comment: Is it now according to your standards, sir?

Comment: @Medi1Saif: Did you really downvote my question? For what reason? I have the changed you didn't like about my post. So I don't the problem.

Comment: I rarely down-vote questions I might down-vote answers yes, but questions are the basis of this site, so to get a down-vote they must have really strong issues. Note that the fact that a question is closed doesn't mean it is bad or can't get upvotes. Also note -as a comment on your edited post- that if your sisters husband hit her it is she who should search juridical help not your family revenge. But in fact in many Muslim countries revenge and many non-Islamic practices have taken overhand such as a wife that leaves the house of her husband if he told he she I divorced.

Comment: @Medi1Saif: With all due respect I first asked if you're the one who downvoted. I didn't accuse yet. My apologies if it came across as unpolite. And I'll take note of that in future questions inshallah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Verse (2:194)](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(2:194:7))

> ...So whoever has assaulted you, then assault him in the same way that
>   he has assaulted you. And fear Allah and know that Allah is with those
>   who fear Him.

[Verse (16:126)](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(16:126:3))

> And if you punish [an enemy, O believers], punish with an equivalent
>   of that with which you were harmed. But if you are patient - it is
>   better for those who are patient.

Hadith:

> فَمَنْ عَفَا وَأَصْلَحَ فَأَجْرُهُ عَلَى اللَّهِ
>   Whoever forgives and makes reconciliation, his reward is with Allah (means, that will not be wasted with Allah.)

All of your Scenarios need a different answer, and in every scenario, being patient and expect better rewards  from Allah is the best option.

Comment: I'll try keep my calm when I'll ever be confronted with those persons. Thank you for your answer.